# Use fputcsv create a .csv file and also update the page with table data

Tags: php, csv, fopen, fputcsv

I am using `fputcsv` to create a .csv file and download it automatically for the user. This works great:

```
function create_csv($data, $not_valid, $csv_old_count, $file_name) {

    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"');

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    foreach ( $data as $line ) {
        fputcsv($fp, $line);
    }
    fclose($fp);
    exit();

}
```

But, I would also like to update the page with a table that shows the data that was put into the csv file. When trying to do this by removing `exit()` and adding a loop to write the table, that data also get written to the csv file instead of writing to my page.

**How can I create and download the .csv and also write some HTML to the page?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the output to your `foreach()` -

```
foreach ( $data as $line ) {
    fputcsv($fp, $line);
    $newLines .= $line . "<br />"; // you'll have to figure out formatting
}
fclose($fp);
echo $newLines; // place this where you want to display the lines
```